# Как добавить иконку в simple_list_item_1?

Tags: android, listview

Подскажите пожалуйста как дополнить мой код? Я получаю данные из xml файла, все корректно отображается, пытаюсь вывести иконку (Получаю ее ссылкой из подгружаемого файла, и через пикасу пытаюсь отобразить) в этот же список, но ничего не происходит, или вместо всех элементов отображается только один, иконки нет все равно. Пытался указать вместо   simple_list_item_1  свой xml, но выдает ошибку. Что я делаю не так?

```
charInfo = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.charList);
    final ArrayList<String> charList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Thread getNerverNews = new Thread()
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {

            try {
                XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
                factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
                XmlPullParser parser = factory.newPullParser();
                URL input = new URL("char.xml");
                parser.setInput(input.openStream(), null);
                while (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT)
                {
                    if (parser.getEventType() == XmlPullParser.START_TAG && parser.getName().equals("char"))
                    {
                        charList.add(parser.getAttributeValue(0) + "\n" + "\n"
                                + parser.getAttributeValue(1) + "\n"
                                + parser.getAttributeValue(2) + "\n"
                                + parser.getAttributeValue(3) + "\n");

                        pathToIcon = parser.getAttributeValue(4);
                        Picasso.with(context).load("pathToIcon").into((Target) charInfo);
                    }
                    parser.next();
                }
            } catch (Throwable t) {
                //Toast.makeText(this, "Ошибка при загрузке XML-документа: " + t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    };
    getNerverNews.start();
    ArrayAdapter<String> charAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, charList);
    charInfo.setAdapter(charAdapter);
```

Comment: В каком месте тут добавляются иконки в адаптер? К тому же разметка [simple_list_item_1.xml](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/simple_list_item_1.xml) не отображает картинок.

Comment: Я новичек в этом, потому и обратился за помощью, не понимаю как добавить картинку, список создавал, но не понял как его прикрутить в адаптер

Comment: В общем то тема уже затертая, может кто то и захочет в очередной раз повторять все. Пока [как то так попробуйте](https://www.google.ru/webhp?UTF-8#q=android%20listview%20with%20icons) Нужна кастомная разметка, как минимум.

Comment: Я уже пользовался подобными запросами, но, как я уже сказал, не понимаю как это сделать на основе моего кода

Comment: В том же файле, где и ListView, создал ImageView, и добавляю таким образом   Picasso.with(context).load(pathToIcon).into(charIcon);   но толку опять же ноль

Comment: Так и должно быть. Вам нужно создать свою разметку айтема, которую использовать вместо simple_list_item_1.xml, затем сделать кастомный адаптер, который будет работать с этой разметкой и биндить на нее данные.

Comment: Попробовал использовать ` Glide.with(context).load("произвольная ссыль на файл").centerCrop().into(charIcon);` и вытащил его из моего потока(где происходит парс информации) - все работает иначе нет... каким образом можно это поправить?